# What does this perl regular expression do?

Tags: perl

Can anyone explain me this regular expression? what does this $% do? I just dont have any idea.

```
$self = "/usr/bin/XYZ";

$self =~s%/+[^/]*$%%;

print ("$self\n");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you put it in a little file and run it?  There's nothing like trying things yourself.  Not only do you learn more, you can play around with it to find more interesting things about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

% is being used as a delimiter to avoid having to escape the / characters
It could be rewritten

```
$self=~s/\/+[^\/]*$//;
```

so $ is the end of string anchor. The expression is replacing:-

```
\/+    - one or more forward slashes
[^\/]* - any number of anything that is not a forward slash
$      - at the end of the string
```

with nothing.
so stripping something like `/end of string` off

Answer (score 3):

The % is used instead of the more common // separators because the pathnames generally contain a lot of / and you'd have to escape them otherwise. The $ matches simply the end of the line. The second % is the end of the substitution pattern which in this case is empty.

As for the meaning of the regexp - it means find something starting with a / and ending with the end of line with no / in the between. Basically you'll get the XYZ that way and substitute it with nothing which leaves out /usr/bin.

Comment: +1 beat me by 2 seconds. the two %% just mean that the replacement string is empty.

Comment: Silly me, I didn't notice it was substitution. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The percent sign is being used as the delimiter for s instead of the more common s/pattern/replacement/. So the dollar sign immediately preceding it is the end-of-line anchor.